# redirect to specific port without apache

Tags: domain-name-system, port, web-hosting

I'm running a few small web applications listening on different ports... 8787, 8888, & 8000. None of them are apache though. Is there any way via either DNS or iptables, or some other way, that I can redirect different sub-domains to the particulat port #? For example, ex1.example.com would redirect to port 8787, ex2.example.com to 8888, etc.

Since I'm not running apache, I'd rather not have to install & configure vhosts just for this, unless there's no other practical way.

thanks!

Comment: Even if you find some hack iptables module to do this, it won't work with SSL. The right way to do it is with vhosts.

Comment: Thanks-- I decided to go with web forwarding from my dns/domain registrar. Kludge-ish, but no more server overhead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are describing requires layer 7 awareness.

Look at details around reverse proxy such as nginx, apache, haproxy.

DNS doesn't give you any control over port. Iptables might work.

Comment: Thanks-- Knowing DNS itself coulnn't do it gave me the info needed. I ultimately went through my domain & DNS provider (gandi.net) which includes web forwarding service. A bit of a kludge, but for the handful of forwards needed it's easier than running another webserver and incurring the overhead.